# How is UltimateListTextCtrl in wxPython used

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a list control which should contain check boxes, list boxes and text entry fields.
The way to go seems to be wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl
The check boxes and list boxes are straight forward enough, but in order to create a text entry field i gather that i need to use UltimateListTextCtrl, but i can't seem to figure out how to use it.
The first argument is "owner", which is a UltimateListCtrl, which seems reasonable. But the second argument, "ItemEdit" should be an instance of UltimateListItem.

I have tried:

```
        item = ULC.UltimateListItem()
        textctrl = ULC.UltimateListTextCtrl(self.ultimateList, item)
        self.ultimateList.SetItem(0,1, textctrl)
```

but this yields a TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'UltimateListItem' and 'int'
I have also tried various integer arguments for ItemEdit since it seems it is compared to an int, but this only yields Exception: invalid item index in GetItem

(the self.ultimateList works fine without the above code)

I also can't seem to find other controls in wx.lib.agw that are instantiated using these arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, sort of.
No need to use UltimateListTextCtrl, a normal wx.TextCtrl works fine. Something like this:

```
    index = self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(sys.maxsize, "Item")
    textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.ultimateList, -1, "default")
    self.ultimateList.SetItemWindow(index, 1, textctrl, expand=True)
```